# Is KafkaTemplate transactional send sync or async?

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm trying to figure out how to proper handle **atomically multiple writes** to **kafka** in a **transactional context**. In this scenario the transaction is not initiated by a kafka message listener but programmatically with @Transactional annotation, see snippet below.

I'm using spring-boot 2.4.2 and spring-kafka 2.6.5.

The KafkaProducer documentation says that in a transactional context it is not required to call .get() on the returned Future because it will eventually throw an Exception when trying to commit the transaction. Moreover the KafkaTemplate calls .get() on the Future returned by KafkaProducer so it looks synchronous.

```
  @PostMapping("/ingest/{topic}")
  public ResponseEntity ingest(@PathVariable(value = "topic") String topic, @RequestBody String numbersString) {

    List<String> numbers = Arrays.stream(numbersString.split(",")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    kafkaWriterService.writeMany(numbers,topic); 
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
  }

  @Transactional
  @Service
  class KafkaWriterService {

    @Autowired
    KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    public void writeMany(List<String> messages, String topic) {

      for (String message : messages) {
        kafkaTemplate.send(message, topic, topic);
      }
    }
  }
```

So as far as I can see the following KafkaTemplate method

```
protected ListenableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> doSend(ProducerRecord<K, V> producerRecord)
```

waits for the Producer to complete the send and then returns another ListenableFutre and this interface is asyncrhonous.

So is this syncrhonous because we are in a transactional context or should I wait for all ListenableFutures returned by the kafkaTemplate to end? I mean considering that I need to reply back to the caller in a synchronous way.

Thanks, kind regards

Answer (score 0):

No; it only calls `get()` if the future was immediately completed by the send...

```java
        Future<RecordMetadata> sendFuture =
                producer.send(producerRecord, buildCallback(producerRecord, producer, future, sample));
        // May be an immediate failure
        if (sendFuture.isDone()) {
            try {
                sendFuture.get();
            }
...
```

Certain errors occur in the client before the send is actually performed.

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1437

Comment: Can you think of an testable scenario where the error does not occur in the client? I would like to test with an actual async error